# Change Thumb Hover in Gallery to Transparent Gradient Triangle in Squarepace

Tags: css, hover, squarespace

I am building out a Squarespace site in the Wexley Template and I want the hover to look like transparent gradient triangle.

I've added this code to the custom css to get a linear gradient:

```
.thumb:hover:before{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+88&0+0,0.3+30,0.5+50,0.75+65,1+80,1+80 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.75) 65%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 88%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 30%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.75) 65%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 88%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 30%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.75) 65%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 88%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Then I added this to rotate the div

```
transform: rotate(-45deg);
```

But I'm not sure how position it to make it look like a triangle. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just an idea: use [svg](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp) or [canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). Both are features of HTML5